# MySql - Extremely slow simple queries (bad memory config?)

Tags: mysql, database, performance, memory

I have a pretty large database (~150GB) with many tables of different sizes. It's running on a relatively solid server (16GB of RAM, 8 core Xeon), which is not used to its full capacity anyway (usually half of RAM & ~25% of CPU).

But as the database grows, I have more and more problems of queries being extremly slow, even when:

- They seem well optimized (at least well indexed)
- They don't generate filesorts or tmp tables
- They don't use the biggest tables that may not fit in memory

It occurs on a variety of queries, but here is an example of a query that sometimes takes more than 10mn (!):

```
SELECT A.*, B.*, C.*
    FROM A
    INNER JOIN B USING(id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN C
        ON (A.id=C.id AND C.date="2016-01-10")
    WHERE A.field1 > 100
      AND  ( B.field2 REGEXP 'XX|YY'
          OR B.field3 REGEXP 'XX|YY' )
```

And here is [the associated EXPLAIN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aFXb.jpg)

Tables size & indexes are as follow:

- A : 25MB with INDEX(id)
- B : 60MB with INDEX(id)
- C : 600MB with INDEX(id,date)

So ok, it's a full table scan on B, but only on 200k rows, and tables are relatively small (at least they can fit in memory). Index seem fine. So how in the world can it take more than 10mn to process?

Another simpler example that took more than 10s :

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE user_id=1 ORDER BY date ASC
```

Explain says :

```
select_type     SIMPLE
table           messages
type            ref
possible_keys   user_id
key             user_id
key_len         8
ref             const
rows            5157
Extra           Using index condition; Using where
```

Table messages is around 500MB, with INDEX(user_id, date).

Note that all tables are using myIsam (but the problem here is not about table locks).

What I suspect is that the mySql configuration is not optimal, and prevents it to use the free memory, thus making it use disk access, making everything slow. The fact that it also happens with even simpler queries & smaller tables seems to hint at a configuration problem too. But that's just a guess, as I don't see what else could be explaining this.

Also note that usually, these slow queries are much faster (if not instantaneous) when re-executed (because of cache I imagine). Their slowness also depends on the moment of the day (I noticed it was much worse in the early morning) while ressources are never used to full capacity.

Does someone have any idea what could be going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whats your innodb_buffer_pool_size?

Comment: This question looks like a better fit for http://dba.stackexchange.com/ - It seems nice and complete but it's OT here.

Comment: @Mihai > 804MB - does it have an impact on myIsam tables too?

Comment: @Tomalak > Indeed, sorry about that I'm a noob here, I'll check if I have a way to move the topic

Comment: No,I was assuming you use InnoDB. AFAIK, a usual value is between 50 and 75 % of the RAM.If your tables are InnoDB,this might be a problem,because for many rows mysql might get into thrashing,which is the slowest access mode possible.Less than 1 GB on  16 GB is extremely low.

Comment: I've set a vote to migrate the question to the DBA site. If a few more people do the same, the question will move there automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` in each table?

`C` needs `INDEX(date, id)` -- That is *not* the same as `INDEX(date), INDEX(id)`.

`A` needs `INDEX(field1)` (but it may not help)

Don't use `*` unless you really need all the columns.

If you don't need `LEFT JOIN`, use `JOIN`.  That way the index I gave for `C` might be more useful.

As it is, the optimizer decided that a full table scan of `B` was the only useful way to get started.

Please show us what the `REGEXPs` really are; there may be ways to improve them.

`messages` needs `INDEX(user_id, date)`, in that order.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so that we can confirm that you already have that 2-column composite index.

Changing to InnoDB should help some.

For MyISAM, key_buffer_size should be set to about 20% of *available* RAM.  (If the total of your indexes (.MYI files) is less than that, you can go even lower.)  Until you switch to InnoDB, `innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be 0.

If re-executing runs "instantaneously", then you are using the Query cache.  Let's ignore that.  But don't have `query_cache_size` any bigger than 50M.

Slower in the morning?  Perhaps all the caches are cold.  That could be because of a restart or backup every night.

Comment: ID is primary key in all tables (does it make a difference with UNIQUE?) // C has INDEX(id,date) - is that ok in that order? // Join needs to be Outer, all ids are not in C //  messages does have (unique) INDEX(user_id,date) in that order (single index on both columns) // Query cache size is 0 - can it still explain instantaneous queries? // key_buffer_size is 4GB ; MYIs total size is 50GB - is that a pb /// Most queries were running fine at some point and sometimes still are, I really think it's more about memory/config than about queries themselves (though additional optimization can't hurt)

Comment: Instantaneous -- Can't explain.  4GB -- OK.  50GB -- can't cache it all, but "no problem".  If you get rid of `LEFT`, an index needs to _start_ with `date`.